# Django. Star rating multiple form displayed in a grid view not working

Tags: html, django, forms, rating

I've got a little problem. I have a page that is used to rate ski resorts. They are displayed in a grid view and each resort has a star rating form beneath.
The problem is that only the first item in the grid can be rated.
I tried to assign each form an unique id but that didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
class AddRatingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = ResortUserRating
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'resort_rating': forms.RadioSelect()
        }

    def __init__(self, pk,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddRatingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.pk = pk
        self.fields['user'].initial = self.pk

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data


{% for resort in dashboard_resorts %}

                    <div class = "grid-item">
                        {% if resort.img %}
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{resort.img.url}}"  alt 
                            ="Card image cap" height="300px" width="380px">
                        {% endif %}
                        <p> <b>{{resort.name|upper}} </b></p>
                        <p> <b>{{resort.id|upper}} </b></p>

                        <form method="post" action = "{% url 'aplicatie2:rating' %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type = "hidden" name = "user" value = "{{user.id}}">
                            <input  type = "hidden" name = "resorts" value = " 
                            {{resort.id}}">

                            <div class="rate">
                                <input type="radio" name="resort_rating" id="rating1" 
                                 value="1" required /><label for="rating1" title="1"> 
                                </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="resort_rating" id="rating2" 
                                 value="2" required /><label for="rating2" title="2"> 
                                 </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="resort_rating" id="rating3" 
                                    value="3" required /><label for="rating3" title="3"> 
                                </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="resort_rating" id="rating4" 
                                value="4" required /><label for="rating4" title="4"> 
                                </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="resort_rating" id="rating5" 
                                value="5" required /><label for="rating5" title="5"> 
                                </label>
                                </div>
                            <br>
                            <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" value = 
                            "submit">
                            {{form.errors}}
                        </form>
                    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are re-using the name attribute and IDs in different groups of radio buttons. These should be unique.  Because of this, all the HTML generated in your for loop is really only creating one set of radio buttons.

One way to solve this is to use the forloop.counter in your template to add a unique element to the names and ids in each loop.

```
 <input type="radio" name="resort_rating_group{{forloop.counter}}" id="rating_group{{forloop.counter}}_1" 
 value="1" required /><label for="rating_group{{forloop.counter}}_1" title="1"> 
 </label>
 <input type="radio" name="resort_rating_group{{forloop.counter}}" id="rating_group{{forloop.counter}}_2" 
 value="1" required /><label for="rating_group{{forloop.counter}}_2" title="2"> 
 </label>
```